# Kubernetes cluster creating issues

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-cluster

Here I'm was using kubernetes for create the cluster manage with all my containers,Now i have some issues on that
 - I'm using this command to install kubernetes:-

```
# dnf install docker cockpit cockpit-docker cockpit-kubernetes kubernetes etcd kubeadm -y
# docker version
# docker-ce-17.09.0.ce-1.fc26
```

This is my current status on kubernetes & docker.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This My current Status in the kubernetes cluster
When I Initialized Kubernetes Cluster have this kind of error

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not add text output as images. Add it as text with an indentation of 4 spaces. And please include only relevant parts of your output.

Comment: You can use Kontena to deploy k8s clusters, if you do not have very specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I did use below URL for deploy three node cluster.
https://blog.alexellis.io/kubernetes-in-10-minutes/

Note: if you want to start only single node cluster, then run taint command as per describe in above URL on master node so container can launch on master node also and if you want to run worker node separately then launch separate vm/vms and run command from start to till swapoff command then join vm to master.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed a step in this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

You seem to have not created a [Pod network Add-on](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) , create a local pod network such as flannel etc.